# How to implement common tap Gesture which will work for all View controllers

Tags: ios, tap

i want to use one common tap gesture for show/hide slider view in view controller with multiple View controller classes.
please provide solution how to implement this for ios .

slider view will show / hide by tap of view of View Controller.
and slider view contain tableview so tableview cell also be select when user click on tableview cell in ios.

is there any way to create a Abstract class for that.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add tapgesture to main content view of VC like,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];

self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

And hanlde tap in method like,

```
-(void)handleTap : (UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

     NSLog(@"tap detect");
 }
```

Hope this will help :)